# Using Jep to modify java object

Tags: python, java

I've read a lot of documentation and questions here on Stack Overflow, but I'm still struggling to accomplish the task.

I have a java object (JobInitDTO) that I created. I want to be able to run an embedded python code that will get the Java object and will be able to manipulate the object using getters and setters on the Python side. Eventually the object that will be returned from the Python function should be the same Java object- after the required modifications.

On my java side I have:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String pythonFolder = System.getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    String jepPath = pythonFolder + "/libjep.jnilib";

    if (!Files.exists(Path.of(jepPath))){
        jepPath = pythonFolder + "/libjep.so";
    }
    MainInterpreter.setJepLibraryPath(jepPath);

    // set path for python docs with python script to run
    jep.JepConfig jepConf = new JepConfig();
    jepConf.addIncludePaths(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/Python/");
    jepConf.addIncludePaths(pythonFolder);
    SharedInterpreter.setConfig(jepConf);
    SharedInterpreter subInterp = new SharedInterpreter();

    subInterp.eval("import Profiler");


    JobInitDTO jobInitDTO = new JobInitDTO();
    subInterp.set("job",jobInitDTO);
    subInterp.eval("res = p.getJobInit(job)");
    System.out.println(subInterp.getValue("res"));
```

On the Python side, the profiler.py file indeed receives the Object, but I can't use its functions or access its fields. To my understanding, I need to represent the java object on the Python side, and this is where I'm struggle to find out how to achieve it.

Profiler.py looks something like that:

```
def getJobInit(job):
     
     <set stuff in job>

     return job
```

Will appreciate your help!

Comment: I removed the [jep] tag as this question isn't related to Java Enhancement Proposals and there doesn't seem to be a tag for the `jep` library.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed. Apparently when using Jep, it is possible to import the Java object on the Python side and call its functions. No extra work is needed on the Python side.